# How can I disaster recover data from a FreeNAS device?

Tags: data-recovery, freenas

I've read here about using FreeNAS and an old personal computer to prepare a home NAS.

If my hardware dies (the PC is very old), will I be able to recover data easily just using the FreeNAS HDDs in another PC?

I'll need Linux to read data, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as I'm aware unless you have a multiple drive failure you can just move the disks to another PC and everything should be fine.

Comment: +1, but should also note that the other PC should be BSD based... had a few FS problems using Ubuntu... Can't remember off by heart the exact details.

Comment: Mmmh... You think I could use another FS instead of BSD one so I'm sure to get compatibility in case of hardware failure?

Comment: I meant including the boot disk so it would effectively be the same system just in a different box

Comment: @pitto There's no reason you couldn't just set up an ubuntu server with samba to the same job, it's less of single purpose OS so a bit more complex to set up but you can do it.

Comment: I have a little experience on Ubuntu and I'd be able to set it up but I'd fight way too much to add user based authorization on folders and sice is for a small office of a friend my mobile phone will start to ring a lot when they want tweaks. Just plain and ultra simple FreeNAS will do honestly the job (with almost-zero assistance :P)
But thank you for the idea anyway :)

Comment: I can understand that, I just found it a little more flexible.  I installed webmin so at least I could configure users etc. remotely and it was only for me so the permissions were a bit of a non issue.